# Custom FUIEmailEntryViewController does not show the email input field

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

Default one shows the field, but once I add the delegate method to use my custom one, the field disappeared.

Do I have to add it myself? If so, how do I pass the content to firebase? Can I get an example of the Customized email entry viewcontroller? I tried to find it on their official website, found nothing.

Thanks!

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. In order to get help, please post the code relevant to your questions and make sure to highlight what you have already tried to achieve what you want.

Comment: "Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)"

Comment: The [GitHub](https://github.com/firebase/FirebaseUI-iOS/blob/master/FirebaseAuthUI/README.md) guide has a lot of information about implementation and use of FUIEmailEntryViewController